# Magento - Want to insert records in magento in admin section

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Hi all i am new with magento and i am trying to insert records in database in admin section. This is a function of controller file.

```
public function saveAction()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $arrData = array('number_of_products'=>$data['number_of_products'],'price'=>$data['price']);  
        $model = Mage::getModel('a/totebags')->setData($arrData);  
        try {  
            $insertId = $model->save()->getId();  
            echo "Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: ".$insertId;  
        } catch (Exception $e){  
            echo $e->getMessage();  
        }  
    }
```

My Question is that when run this code then i got this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on a non-object in /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/app/code/community/ToteBags/Adminform/controllers/Adminhtml/AdminformController.php on line 40
```

This is my `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ToteBags_Adminform>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </ToteBags_Adminform>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <totebags_adminform>
                <class>ToteBags_Adminform_Block</class>
            </totebags_adminform>
        </blocks>

        <helpers>
            <totebags_adminform>
                <class>ToteBags_Adminform_Helper</class>
            </totebags_adminform>
        </helpers>

        <models>
            <totebags_adminform>
                <class>ToteBags_Adminform_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>totebags_adminform_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </totebags_adminform>
            <totebags_adminform_mysql4>
                <class>ToteBags_Adminform_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <category>
                        <table>totebags_fbstore_category</table>
                    </category>
                    <category_product>
                        <table>totebags_fbstore_category_product</table>
                    </category_product>
                </entities>
            </totebags_adminform_mysql4>
        </models>

        <resources>
            <totebags_adminform_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>ToteBags_Adminform</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </totebags_adminform_setup>
            <totebags_adminform_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </totebags_adminform_write>
            <totebags_adminform_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </totebags_adminform_read>
        </resources>
    </global>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <totebags_adminform after="Mage_Adminhtml">ToteBags_Adminform_Adminhtml</totebags_adminform>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <totebags_adminform>
                    <file>totebags_adminform.xml</file>
                </totebags_adminform>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <ToteBags_Adminform>
                    <files>
                        <default>ToteBags_Adminform.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </ToteBags_Adminform>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>

    <default>
        <totebags_adminform>
            <general>
                <default_sort_by><![CDATA[position]]></default_sort_by>
            </general>
        </totebags_adminform>
    </default>
</config>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried seeing if `Mage::getModel('a/totebags')` is returning an object?

Comment: Here's a similar thread of people having problems: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/71277/

Comment: Thanks @justerb for this link i will read it now.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't configured your module resources correctly.  What does your `config.xml` look like and what files do you have in the `Model` directory of your module?

Comment: I have updated my question with my `config.xml`

Comment: Ok, and what about under the `Model` directory?  You need at the very least a resource file as well as the actual model class.

Answer (score 0):

Did you upload app/etc/modules/modulename.xml file that has codePool details something like this

true
            core

replace Mage_Connect by namespace_modulename

Looks like above part you have done.

Controller is not extended using class Varien_Object so there is no setData to be used with Controller class instance.
$model = Mage::getModel('a/totebags')->setData($arrData);

what class is extended to create your Model.You have probably extended some controller.
As error points to some controller.